# HTML письма

Tags: html, css

Каким образом можно с gmail оправлять письма написанные на html. Пробовал просто вставлять в письмо html и пересылать, приход голый html код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С самого сайта gmail никак. Используй почтовый клиент (The Bat, mozilla thunderbird, или на крайний случай microsoft outlook)